# Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism in WAR files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, war, endorsed

How are you supposed to provide Endorsed Standards Overrides with WAR files? Our application has some dependencies that depend on a recent version of apache xerces (at least 2.9.1).

The [documentation of glassfish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gchif.html) suggests to put the jar in `domaindir/lib/endorsed`, but that would be a manual step required at installation. Is there a way to provide the library directly in the WAR file, so that the adminstrator can just deploy the war file with one command and be good?

Comment: I don't believe so, the usual issue is that the class-loader used for loading the war file has already loaded an earlier version of xerces.

Comment: If I read [the chapter about classloaders](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/class-loaders.htm) correctly, and specifically the paragraph about delegation, adding the jar(s) to your project and adding `delegate="false"` to glassfish-web.xml might be the solution (that setting gives classes found in the application archive priority).

Comment: @fvu: Thanks for the suggestion, it seems promising but fails with the same error like just putting xerces in the classpath (`DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory`).